# Is it possible to update credit card details as part of a doreferencetransaction call with the credit card details fields?

Tags: paypal

The Paypal DoReferenceTransaction API call has a section called 'Reference Credit Card Details Fields':

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/DoReferenceTransaction_API_Operation_NVP/

Why?  If you're making a reference transaction, you're purposefully *not* taking credit card details, but using the paypal token.  What is the use case for adding credit card details with a doreferencetransaction request?

The real reason I'm asking is that I'm curious if it's possible to update the stored details associated with the transaction ID (specifically the credit card expiration date), and it seems like that *might* be possible with the credit card details field.

Comment: I've never tested the other credit card fields in DoReferenceTransaction to see how the system reacts, but I know the CVV2 is often required in DRT requests because many times the merchant PayPal account is setup to decline payments where the CVV2 is not included or doesn't match.  For PCI compliance reasons, PayPal can't include the CVV2 code in their data when they save card details, so if the account is setup to require it, it has to be included in DRT calls even though PayPal has all the other info already.

Answer (score 1):

As strange a call as it is (support has been sporadic for it), DRT is probably not going to work like that. I've never tried it like this, but I do know that providing the CVV2 for the card is not always successful. The only success I've ever had with it is after turning off CVV2 mismatch checking and running the transaction through.

If I were you, I would run a new authorization for $1, void it, and replace the transaction ID with the new one. I've had success doing that.